# Regex should not match if special character found anywhere in the string

Tags: regex

Please help me!

I am parsing strings which contain weights.
But here is the catch: some strings contain range (see line 3 of that example below), which I consider an ambiguous value and do not want to match at all.

examples are:

```
1.0kg - should return group(1)='1.0', group(2)='kg'
400.00g - should return group(1)='400.00', group(2)='g'
100-800g - right now returns group(1)='800', group(2)='g', but should not return match!
```

Regex I am using right now is:

```
r"([\d.,]+)(g|kg)"
```

**How to modify it to exclude 3rd line from returning a match?**

Right now I check if string contains '-' before using a regex, but I wonder how to do it using a regex patter without extra if-else statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex pattern:

```
(?<!-)\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\wg
```

This pattern excludes numbers which are immediately preceded by a dash, while still also requiring that the matching number is bounded on the left by a word boundary.

Explanation:

- `(?<!-)` assert that hyphen does not preceded (eliminate `100-800g`)
- `\b` but still match a word boundary
- `\d+` match an integer
- `(?:\.\d+)?` optional decimal component
- `\w` single letter unit in front of grams
- `g` match 'g' for grams

Here is a working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jqk4wC/2).

Comment: This also prevents the regex from matching negative numbers, which may or may not be a problem.

Comment: @tripleee There is no such thing as negative mass in this world (save perhaps except for antimatter, which I doubt the OP is dealing with).

Comment: There are many contexts where you specify a delta like -5kg after your weight loss treatment.